# On Widows, how can I screen capture, then paste as JPG (not PNG) into gmail?

Tags: windows-10, copy-paste, jpeg, image-conversion

How can I capture part of a screen on Windows 10, then paste as a JPG?
Using the inbuilt snipping tool and third party tools, the resulting pasted image ends up as a PNG in Gmail.
PNG files are significantly larger for photographic images.

I can get a JPG by capturing using most any tool, saving a JPG, then uploading the result into Gmail.
But that's a lot of extra mousestrokes.

See also: [How to Paste a picture as JPG instead of PNG](https://superuser.com/questions/1511410/how-to-paste-a-picture-as-jpg-instead-of-png)

Comment: You need to use third-party screen capture tools.

Comment: Also Paste Special can convert to JPG in Word but not in Outlook (so far as I can see) . Accordingly, in Email you are probably best to upload the file into Gmail.   Word has more format capabilities.  I used SnagIT for testing.

Comment: As noted above, I've tried  third-party screen capture tools.

Comment: You might try [Greenshot](https://github.com/greenshot/greenshot).